Is P/poly is contained in NP?
I learned that $\textsf{P/poly}$ is a class of problems computable by a polynomial-size circuit.
This class is considered a class of problems such that there exists a polynomial-time algorithm that is given a bitstring of $\textsf{poly}(n)$ length when the size of the input is $n$.
On the other hand, $\textsf{NP}$ is a class of problems where for any problem, there exists a poly-time algorithm $M$ such that for every input $x$, it is true iff there exists a bitstring $\alpha \in \{0,1\}^{\textsf{poly}(|x|)}$ such that $M(x,\alpha) = 1$.
Then, does it hold $\textsf{P/poly} \subseteq \textsf{NP}$ ?
I have searched for such results but found only the results about the inverse relation $\textsf{NP} \subseteq \textsf{P/poly}$.
Could you tell me the fact!!
I think that a bitstring of $\textsf{P/poly}$ is also used as the certification of $\textsf{NP}$.

$\mathbf{P}_{/poly}\not\subseteq\mathbf{NP}$.
For $L\in\mathbf{P}_{/poly}$, there exists a polynomial-time TM $M$, a polynomial $p:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$, and a sequence $\{\alpha_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of strings with $\alpha\in\{0,1\}^{p(n)}$ satifying $$x\in L\iff M(x,\alpha_n)$$ for every $x\in\{0,1\}^n$. That means $\alpha_n$ is the certificate of all n-length strings. What if a n-length string $x$ s.t. $M(x,\alpha_n)=0$, but there is another polynomial-length certificate, say, $\beta$ satisfying $M(x,\beta)=1$? In that case the TM $M$ cannot prove that $L\in\mathbf{NP}$, $x$ must be in $L$ by $\mathbf{NP}$ definition, but $x$ must not be in $L$ by $\mathbf{P}_{/poly}$ definition. So we should find another polynomial-time TM, if any.
$\mathbf{P}_{/poly}$ contains undecidable languages, for example $A=\{1^n|\text{ $n$ is binary encode of the $n$th halting Turing machine}\}$. $A\notin\mathbf{NP}$ thanks to Halting theorem. In other words, no polynomial-time TM is able to prove $A\in\mathbf{NP}$.
Besides, we also don't know whether $\mathbf{NP}\subseteq\mathbf{P}_{/poly}$ since witnesses of same-length strings in a $\mathbf{NP}$ language can be different.
